# Android & AndroidPC: how to install Git-SCM?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, git, android

I see several apps from the Play store. They are either Terminal or Terminal emulating apps (emulation provides the supposedly similar functionality, validation?). The Termux is becoming a popular name.

With the Android system evolving, if far as AndroidPC operating system (PhoenixOS, ChromeOS, Remix, Sailfish, Console OS..correct me if Console OS is for playstation devices only), the capability of using your system as a desktop is widened. 
However, the developers have yet provided any concern about the capability to run Cli applications (Git bash, Python py.exe, Ruby, NodeJS, MongoDB, even PHP, MySQL, programming and layering compilers, ...). You're not just about writing code on a white text editor. Most of the time, most of us find that we need testing along-side with development...much to the point of TDD.

I see the Android is quite stable and fast (unless messing around with unfit pkgs after root), the AndroidPC OS are fast and so nimble too. But problem is they are developed to target end-users with emphasis on the interface, while developer users want less distraction, simplicity (simpler GUIs, straight-forward, less clusterred, less clunky-junky), Terminal empowered to perhaps full of its potential..

Another problem with the core of their environment aiming at end-users with high reliance on the internet access (everything goes on the Cloud, Cloud-based sytems - ChromeOS is such a representative..). If you are to use a Cloud IDE, you are likely to pay a lot for 4G, mobile bandwidth...$40-50 a month is not bad but I would sum all that by 12 months and try to get an Ultrabook to carry around with me instead.. I mean from my perspective of a developer, I want a real desktop environment (lightning fast and nimble as Remix, PhoenixOS or PeppermintOS, UbuntuMATE, LinuxMint (if you want to talk about Linux distros, ofc, much better than Windows, much less hiccup, security loophole, corrupt boot-loader, much more worry-free). The desktop env is able to run Cli applications and then sync to my online repos, resources, and services whenever I gain internet connection later.

Have you been able to install Git and other CLi applications on Android and AndroidPC? How? You documented what you did (guide, tut, protocol..)?  What have you found about Android and AndroidPC operating systems?..any experience in using NOT for entertainment BUT for development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For reference: In [Termux](https://termux.com/) you can install git with

```
apt install git
```